# What does it mean A contains a field k mapping isomorphically onto the residue field A/m in Atiyah Macdonald 11.21?

Tags: commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I'm reading Atiyah Macdonald 11.21.

[image]

But I'm not sure what "A contains a field k mapping isomorphically onto the residue field A/m" means and have no idea to apply proposition 11.20

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is a field $k\subset A$ such that the induced map $k\subset A\to A/\mathfrak m$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean that the restriction of quotient map to k is an isomorphism from k to A/m?

Comment: Yes that's precisely what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!